# meteor: using more than one stylesheet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a meteor project with a twitter bootstrap css file and an app styl file. how can i have the styl take precedence over the bootstrap css? i.e. there may be conflicting tags in both files but i'd like not to have to comb through the bootstrap css to remove them.

before adding bootstrap css, my formatting looked just the way i liked it to be. after adding the bootstrap css, some of the formatting was off.

Answer (score 2):

I can not recommend using `!important` rule since it will mess up your code and make it hard to maintain.

In Meteor you can use as much stylesheets as you like you just have to keep the load order in mind:

> - Files in the lib directory at the root of your application are loaded first.
> - Files that match main.* are loaded after everything else.
> - Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent directories, so that files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded
>     first (after lib), and files in the root directory are loaded last
>     (other than main.*).
> - Within a directory, files are loaded in alphabetical order by filename.
>
> These rules stack, so that within lib, for example, files are still
>   loaded in alphabetical order; and if there are multiple files named
>   main.js, the ones in subdirectories are loaded earlier.

For more info take a look at [docs.meteor.com](http://docs.meteor.com/).

Answer (score 1):

To save your effort in long run, I highly recommend using SASS!