# prevent to merge all assets in meteor.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, meteor, meteoric, meteor-cordova

I try to create **mobile application** with a **web based admin dashboard** using [meteor.js](http://meteor.com/) and I want to use one app approach based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237778/meteor-one-backend-multiple-different-front-ends-2x-web-and-1x-mobile), because I have many code that share between clients (mobile or web) with server.

I try to separate clients layout for different view. (using [iron-router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router) facilities) like this:

```
// set mobileLayout for all routes
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'mobileLayout',
    notFoundTemplate: "notFound",
    loadingTemplate: "loading"
});

// add specific adminLayout for admin routes
LoginController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: "adminLayout",

    template: "login",

    action: function () {
        this.render();
    }
});
```

I used [meteoric](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic) for mobile view platform and [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for my admin dashboard. But some conflict occurred in CSS (for example I set font for mobile app and it's override web version fonts too and I need add specific CSS selector for almost everything) and also **It's not best solution because meteor merge all css and js together while mobile client don't use bootstrap at all and admin web users also don't use meteoric.**

***My question is:***

How to tell meteor to merge mobile assets (CSS, and template JS) together and merge web assets together to have smaller mobile app and smaller web app and prevent CSS conflict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [meteor: using more than one stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143831/meteor-using-more-than-one-stylesheet)

Comment: You could create a [CompileStep](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/CompileStep-API-for-Build-Plugin-Source-Handlers) plugin, split your app into 2 separate apps and have them share libraries (packages) and database (which is a pretty good approach, IMHO) or use an alternative build system (such as Webpack). It is not just the stylesheet, it is also the entire code for the admin panel that gets shipped to your mobile app.